# Hippo cms add content to repository

Tags: jcr, hippocms

This time I'm trying add a values to repository using component. I don't have problem with reading.

Currently, I'm trying add the city to the repository

My code:

```
Session session = this.getPersistableSession(request);
HippoBean siteBaseBean = request.getRequestContext().getSiteContentBaseBean();
HippoBean hippoFolder = siteBaseBean.getBean("city"); 
Node node = hippoFolder.getNode();

String path = node.getPath(); // it's working "/content/documents/myhippoproject/city"

node.addNode("4","hippo:handle");
session.save();
```

after this code nothing happened. I tried also:

```
node.addNode("4",HippoNodeType.HIPPO_NODE);
```

No errors and node.

Comment: From which method are you trying to do this in a component? doAction or doBeforeRender?

Comment: doBeforeRender. what is the difference? I'm using curl POST and downloading data to JSONOBject , but it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, I found a solution.

```
Session session = this.getPersistableSession(request);
    HippoBean siteBaseBean = request.getRequestContext().getSiteContentBaseBean();
HippoBean hippoFolder = siteBaseBean.getBean("city"); 
    Node node = hippoFolder.getNode();

HippoRepository repository = HippoRepositoryFactory.getHippoRepository("vm://");
            Session session2 = repository.login("admin", "admin".toCharArray());


            HstRequestContext requestContext = request.getRequestContext();
            WorkflowPersistenceManager wpm = null;
            wpm = getWorkflowPersistenceManager(session2);
            wpm.setWorkflowCallbackHandler(new BaseWorkflowCallbackHandler<DocumentWorkflow>() {
                public void processWorkflow(DocumentWorkflow wf) throws Exception {
                    wf.requestPublication();
                }
            });
String name = "12";

wpm.createAndReturn(node.getPath(), "myhippoproject:City", name, false);

City city = (City) wpm.getObject(node.getPath() + "/" + name);
                wpm.update(city);
                session2.save();
```